# how to use dictionnaries to translate inputs to numbers/letters

Tags: python

I want a python code that translate numbers to specific letters and the opposite (not only  alphabetically) , and i wonder if there is a way for doing that using dictionaries , and how to specify the number of digits to translate . for example the input would be : 1203
so how to control if the program would translate each digit individually,in pairs or in more complicated ways .

Comment: If, for example, you chose `1` to represent `A`, `2` to represent `B`, and `12` to represent `L`, how would your code handle something like `211212`? How would it know to interpret it as, say `BALL` rather than `BAABAB` or `BALAB` or whatever? We need much more detailed examples. Maybe check the [ask] page, the [tour], and the [mre] page to see how you can clarify your question to better fit this site's question requirements.

Comment: `m = str(1203)` will give `m = '1203'`, the numbers in a string. Now use as many digits as you want. e.g., for 1 digit at a time, a loop like `m[i]` or for 2 digits, `m[i:i+2]`. As for the translation part, your question is not clear enough. Give some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ascii code and the `built-in` function `chr(number)`:

```
chr(32)
```

result:

```
' '
```

but this enables just one per character, so you could do something like this:

### DISCLAMER: the code isn't efficent, its just for example:

```
number = '1234'
dgs = []
digits = ""
for digit in number:
    if digits == '':
        digits+=digit;continue

    if int(digits+digit) <= 255:
        print(digit,"has been appended to ",digits)

        digits+=digit

    if int(digits+digit) > 255:
        print("the queque is full, list ",digits,"cleared!")
        dgs.append(int(digits));digits = ''
if digits != '':
        dgs.append(int(digits))
        print(digits)
        digits=''
decoded = [chr(x) for x in dgs]
print(dgs,decoded)
```

output:

```
[123,4] ['{', '\x04']
```

if you want to be in a single string, you could `join` them together, using the `join` method:

```
string_stdout = ''.join(decoded)
print(string_stdout)
```

out:

```
{♦
```